# $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- StatusModalService giving error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

Trying to built a modal with angularjs and ui-bootstrap:

Version

- Angularjs and its component is 1.5.3
- ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js.

In main app file I have included *'ui.bootstrap'* as

```
var App = angular.module('aotaApp', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap','checklist-model','ngSanitize'])
.controller("myController", function($scope,$state, $http)
```

In StatusService I am using this as

```
App.service("StatusModalService", ["$uibModal",
                          function ($uibModal) {
     var modalDefaults = {
         backdrop: true,
         keyboard: true,
         modalFade: true,
         templateUrl: 'resources/template/modal/confirmationModal.html'
     };
    var modalOptions = {
         closeButtonText: 'Close',
         actionButtonText: 'OK',
         headerText: 'Proceed?',
         bodyText: 'Perform this action?'
     };

     this.showModal = function (customModalDefaults, customModalOptions) {
         if (!customModalDefaults) customModalDefaults = {};
         customModalDefaults.backdrop = 'static';
         return this.show(customModalDefaults, customModalOptions);
     };

     this.show = function (customModalDefaults, customModalOptions) {
         //Create temp objects to work with since we're in a singleton service
         var tempModalDefaults = {};
         var tempModalOptions = {};

         //Map angular-ui modal custom defaults to modal defaults defined in service
         angular.extend(tempModalDefaults, modalDefaults, customModalDefaults);

         //Map modal.html $scope custom properties to defaults defined in service
         angular.extend(tempModalOptions, modalOptions, customModalOptions);

         if (!tempModalDefaults.controller) {
             tempModalDefaults.controller = function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
                 $scope.modalOptions = tempModalOptions;
                 $scope.modalOptions.ok = function (result) {
                     $uibModalInstance.close(result);
                 };
                 $scope.modalOptions.close = function (result) {
                     $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                 };
             }
         }

         return $uibModal.open(tempModalDefaults).result;
     };
 }]);
```

But I am  getting error

> angular-1.5.3.js:13424 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- StatusModalService

I am new to angular and mainly found to add ui.bootstrap in app. but it's not giving any help.

Please guide me.

Comment: Here's a plunk with your code https://plnkr.co/edit/cXxZiWjcbNJ8t5p4CmyG?p=preview  It isn't blowing any errors.  Check the versions to see if yours are different.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a version issue, Need to upgrade your  ui-bootstrap

https://github.com/compact/angular-bootstrap-lightbox/issues/42

Comment: I have tried with 0.14.0 also and angular-1.5.3 but no luck the same error. And  this is mention on the **https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/**AngularJS (requires AngularJS 1.4.x or higher, tested with 1.5.3). 0.14.3 is the last version of this library that supports AngularJS 1.3.x and 0.12.0 is the last version that supports AngularJS 1.2.x.

Answer (score 0):

## Install latest version of angular-bootstrap

```
npm install angular-bootstrap or bower install angular-bootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be due to a renaming of `$uibModal`. If you have this error, try using `$modal` instead.